# Selenium xpath: element not visible on Amazon site

Tags: exception, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am trying to write a Selenium test against Amazon site. I want to get "Sign in"  element so that I can click on it.

url: www.amazon.ca

Here is my Selenium Code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@data-nav-role='signin']")).click();
```

But I get `Element not visible` exception.

I have tried putting `Thread.sleep(5000)` before element lookup but still the same issue.

I have other ways to pick the element but I want to find out why this Xpath not working in my code.

Note: When trying it in Chrome DevTool Console, it works fine there `$x("//a[@data-nav-role='signin']")`

Comment: Try this - driver.findElement(By.xpath('//a[@data-nav-role='signin'][1]'))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selector you have chosen returns multiple elements i.e. 3. You can verify that by using `findElements` instead of `findElement`.

You can either give a precise selector for the specific element you want to click on or you can get all matching elements using `findElements`, loop through them and click one with a matching attribute e.g. text.

Try:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("nav-link-yourAccount")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have checked the site and we need to mouse over to the menu before to make the sign in  button visible. Below code might give you some idea.

```
//Mouse over to the menu
Actions action = new Actions(webdriver);
WebElement we = webdriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\'nav-link-yourAccount\']/span[1]"));
action.moveToElement(we).build().perform();
//Now perform sign in button clicking action since its visible now
```

Hope this helps you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try click xpath:

> //a[@id='nav-link-yourAccount']/span